# Mongodb c# update a comment in n-nested comment chain

Tags: c#, mongodb, forum

I've found a few questions about updating children of parent documents,  but only when you already know how far the parent/child tree goes. Here's my model:

```
public class ParentThread
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to use Mongodb's update feature to send new comments to a parent thread without submitting the full thread. This is to avoid issues with multiple users adding threads at the same time and the database overwriting them. The trouble is that I don't know how to specify to mongodb how far down the tree it needs to go in order to add the user's comment to the thread.

I've figured out how to query the document and traverse the tree to find the target comment to add to, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass that as the first parameter of the Update.Push() method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of recommended ways of modelling tree structures. Take a look at [parent references](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/) in the official docs. This will liniarize your tree. The Parent References pattern stores each tree node in a document. In addition to the tree node, the document stores the id of the node’s parent. My proposal below:

```
// item is the base, comment is a thread comment, reply is a comment to a comment
public enum ItemType { Item, Thread, Comment, Reply }

public class Item {
  [BsonId] public string Id { get; set; }
  [BsonElement("body")] public string Body { get; set; }
  [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
  [BsonElement("type")] public virtual ItemType Type { get { return ItemType.Item; } }
  [BsonDefaultValue(null)]
  [BsonElement("parent")] public string ParentId { get; set; }
  [BsonDefaultValue(null)]
  [BsonElement("title")] public string Title { get; set; }
  public override string ToString() { return String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", Id, Type, ParentId, Body, Title); }
}

public class Thread : Item { public override ItemType Type { get { return ItemType.Thread; } } }

public class Comment : Item { public override ItemType Type { get { return ItemType.Comment; } } } 

public class Reply : Item { public override ItemType Type { get { return ItemType.Reply; } } }
```

How to find items, driver version 2.3:

```
IMongoCollection<item> col = ...
// create index for parent column
await col.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Item>.IndexKeys.Ascending(x => x.ParentId));
var root = await (await col.FindAsync(fdb.Eq(x => x.ParentId, null))).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
var rootComments = await (await col.FindAsync(fdb.Eq(x => x.ParentId, root.Id))).ToListAsync();
// same thing for queries for replies to comments
```

Major advantage is the insert. You just have to know the parent for the thing you want to insert. No more nested find issues.